# Matching string in 2 different patterns in PHP. The code must return TRUE

Tags: php, regex

Objective: strings with `'` should match the string without it.

Example:

```
    $first_string  = "alex ern o'brian";
        $second_string = "alex-ern o brian";

        $pattern = array("/(-|\.| )/", "/(')/");
        $replace = array(' ', '(\s|)');
        $first_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $first_string);
        $second_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $second_string);

        $first_string_split = preg_split("/(-|\.| )/", $first_string);
        $first_string_split[] = $first_string;
        $second_string_split = preg_split("/(-|\.| )/", $second_string);
        $second_string_split[] = $second_string;

        $first_string = array_slice($first_string_split, -1)[0];
        $second_string = array_slice($second_string_split, -1)[0];

        if(in_array($first_string, $second_string_split) || in_array($second_string, $first_string_split))
{
            echo 'true';
        } else {
            echo 'false';
        }
```

> 

Comment: Just strip the special characters. `[^a-zA-Z]` if you only want alpha characters.

Comment: @halfman_halfamazing you are expecting, which i have updated in my post.

Comment: @halfman_halfamazing You unaccepted my post is it not working fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are expecting this.

**Solution 1:**   [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/782218)

**Regex:** `(\s|)` this will match either `space` or `null`.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string = "o'brian"; 
$string=str_replace("'", "(\s|)",$string);
$list = array("o'neal", "o brian", "obrian");
$result=array();
foreach($list as $value)
{
    if(preg_match("/$string/", $value))
    {
        $result[]=$value;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

**Solution 2:**

**Regex:** `[a-z]+` will match character from `a` to `z`.

```
$string1="o brian";
$string2="obrian";

if(preg_match("/".implode(" ", $matches[0])."/", $string1))
{
    echo "matched";
}

if( preg_match("/".implode("", $matches[0])."/", $string2))
{
    echo "matched";
}
```

Comment: The OPs `(-|\.'| )`, and this character class are not the same. Although what the OP was doing I'm unclear of. Character class can just be `[-.']`

Comment: @chris85 `The problem: how to make "o'brian" == "obrian" true?` this was the last line of the post, thats why i have updated my post with new and currect expression.

Comment: @chris85 Last time i miss understood OP's question, I think this time i have made a correct post.. Thanks for last time.. :)

Comment: The objective is if I get a string like "o'brian" my script will loop thru the list of names and if in the list there is no "o'brian" but has "obiran" and "o brian" it will return true.

Comment: psuedo
$string = "o'brian";
$list = array("o'neal", "o brian", "obrian");
// returns o brian , obrian

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question right, but this should do it:

```
(?<=\w)'(?=\w)
```

It matches every `'` character, which is followed and preceded by a word character. The word character `\w` is equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

- [Here is a live example to test the regex](https://regex101.com/r/v5wBGB/1)
- [Here is a live PHP example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/438ba4f12b49173ec8b2d5f0b683991c57592272)